# First error: invalid character encoding - Apex Job

Tags: batch, character-encoding, encoding

I have written an apex batch that was working before sendbox refreshing. When I try to run the batch I get this message in the Status Detail:

```
First error: invalid character encoding
```

Instead in the debug log I get error in the status:

```
Internal Salesforce.com Error
```

Is there someone who know what is going on?
Thank you all.

Comment: Further investigation revealed that the batch job does not start if the result set is larger than 500 rows. So I have tried to limit the query to 500 rows:
query += ' WHERE IsClosed = true LIMIT 500'; and Batch works without issues. If I try with more rows (550 or 600 up) I obtain the same error.

Since function used, Database.getQueryLocator, is specified to allow 50 million rows, and I data are around 80 000, there is no obvious explanation to this change in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed some fields. It seems that if there are too many data in an environment and the query structure is complex you get this kind of error.

Comment: Good advice, mate!